# (var) cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, variables, char

I've been using eclipse, and it throws up an error whenever I try to change a value stored in a character array.
Code:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char monstername[] = {'e', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
        String monster = new String(monstername);
        System.out.println("Hello!");
        System.out.println("You are attacked by a " + monster);
        monstername[] = {'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
        System.out.println("You are attacked by a " + monster);
    }
}
```

I tried updating the library but it didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
monstername[] = {'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
```

Won't work for two reasons.

1. It's not valid syntax, so the compiler doesn't know what to do with it.
2. You need to create a new instance of the variable

.

```
monstername = new char[] {'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
```

Because `monster` has already being declared as a char array (`char[]`), you don't need to use [] in the second statement

Comment: Solved my problem AND made me learn something! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
monstername[] = {'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
```

is a valid (partial) declaration, but it is not a valid assignment. It should be

```
monstername = new char[]{'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
monster = new String(monstername);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `[]` don’t belong, and to create an array as an expression, you use `new <type>[]`:

```
monstername = new char[] {'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
```

Comment: While correct, & you & I know why, this would be better answer if you explained why ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: How do I explain why the `[]` don’t belong? It’s difficult 

Comment: I was thinking more about the re-instantiation of the char array, why would you have to do this ;). Monster is already declared as a char[], so you don't need to/can't redeclare it ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: “To create an array as an expression”

Answer (score 0):

you can't update it like that because `monstername[]` is a pointer.

try: `monstername = new char[] {'s', 'm', 't', 'g'};`

Comment: Personally, I'd avoid words like "pointer", while technically correct, you start using it and people want to know why they can't do pointer arithmetic in Java, better to use something like "reference" instead, IMHO

Comment: I'm not that familiar with java anymore as I haven't used it in quite some time but thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

change the lines

```
monstername[] = {'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
System.out.println("You are attacked by a " + monster);
```

to

```
monstername = new char[]{'t', 'v', 'i', 'l'};
System.out.println("You are attacked by a " + new String(monstername));
```